# Dirichlet theorem

Tags: programming

I'm programming Dirichlet theorem - [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)(p mod d=a, p is a prime number) via procedural programming and I don't have any idea, how to start. I would like to have function, which gets three numbers (a,d,k) and give me back first k prime numbers, which fits in equation above.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirichlet theorem states, that in the sequence a+i*d, where a and d are coprime and i integer >0, there are infinite many primes. Therefore we simply check this sequence with increasing i until we findd the requested number of primes:

```
getPrimes[a_, d_, k_] := Module[{i = 0, c = 0},
   Reap[While[c < k, If[PrimeQ[a + ++i d], c++; Sow[a + i d]]]][[2, 1]]
  ]
```

E.g.:

```
getPrimes[3, 7, 5]
(* {17, 31, 59, 73, 101} *)
```

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau. Hi Daniel.  What do you mean by "code". I simply programmed the answer up, checked it at 2 example and posted it.

Comment: Oops. I'm sorry Daniel. I posted my comment under your answer when I meant to place it under the original post. I moved it to where it belongs.